# I can't return String value in Java

Tags: java, string, methods

I have homework that needs me to return a string value for the entered double value. I tried a few things but nothing worked. Probably this is too basic for you but I couldn't find an answer here or anywhere on the internet probably because I didn't know where to look. If you just point out where to look or help me that would be great. Thank you very much!
First I tried this:

```
public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
    if (grade<=34) {
        String c = "FF";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=45 && grade >= 35) {
        String c = "FD";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=52 && grade >= 46) {
        String c = "DD";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=59 && grade >= 53) {
        String c = "DC";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=66 && grade >= 60) {
        String c = "CC";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=73 && grade >= 67) {
        String c = "CB";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=80 && grade >= 74) {
        String c = "BB";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=87 && grade >= 81) {
        String c = "BA";
        return c;
    }
    if (grade<=100 && grade >= 88) {
        String c = "AA";
        return c;
    }
}
```

Well it didn't work so I tried this:

```
public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
    String c = "";
    if (grade<=34) {
        String a = "FF";
    }
    if (grade<=45 && grade >= 35) {
        String a = "FD";
    }
    if (grade<=52 && grade >= 46) {
        String a = "DD";
    }
    if (grade<=59 && grade >= 53) {
        String a = "DC";
    }
    if (grade<=66 && grade >= 60) {
        String a = "CC";
    }
    if (grade<=73 && grade >= 67) {
        String a = "CB";
    }
    if (grade<=80 && grade >= 74) {
        String a = "BB";
    }
    if (grade<=87 && grade >= 81) {
        String a = "BA";
    }
    if (grade<=100 && grade >= 88) {
        String a = "AA";
    }
    return c+a;
}
```

Still no luck... Both are giving compile errors.

Comment: Plz give us more information about this problem what is the error message you are getting and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: *it didn't work* is not an error description. PLease describe what you expect and what is happend

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this didn't work? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: you should consider using else if statements or maybe it would be even better to use switch statements

Comment: It gave a compile error but it is solved now.

Comment: One problem is that grade is a floating point number (a double), and you are leaving places were the if-statements don't cover. If the grade is 87.5, then it won't be seen at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using a local variable in function so it returns null probably you can try that :

```
  public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
    String a = "";
    if (grade<=34) {
         a = "FF";
    }
    if (grade<=45 && grade >= 35) {
         a = "FD";
    }
    if (grade<=52 && grade >= 46) {
         a = "DD";
    }
    if (grade<=59 && grade >= 53) {
         a = "DC";
    }
    if (grade<=66 && grade >= 60) {
         a = "CC";
    }
    if (grade<=73 && grade >= 67) {
         a = "CB";
    }
    if (grade<=80 && grade >= 74) {
         a = "BB";
    }
    if (grade<=87 && grade >= 81) {
         a = "BA";
    }
    if (grade<=100 && grade >= 88) {
         a = "AA";
    }
    return a;
}
```

Let me know if it doestn work

Comment: consider using `else if`

Comment: It did work. I am so stunned because i've been working on this nearly 30 mins and you gave the answer instant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your first case i thing you get a compile erro because you miss a return at the end of the method (outside of the if statement

```
public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
    if (grade<=34) {

...
    if (grade<=100 && grade >= 88) {
        String c = "AA";
        return c;
    }
   return null;
}
```

in the second case you try to access `a` outside of the defined scope:

```
public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
    String a = "";
    if (grade<=34) {
        a = "FF";
    }
    if (grade<=45 && grade >= 35) {
        a = "FD";
    }
    ....
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you you are right. I don't know what return null is but I am sure I will be learning in upcoming classes. Thank you for the answer and the time you gave to my problem.

Comment: @Vecta `null` is like an undefined value. https://dev.to/dj_devjournal/understanding-null-in-java-4o31#:~:text=In%20Java%2C%20null%20is%20a,them%20and%20give%20an%20error. You can also return anyother string here. Importent is to have the return statement

Comment: this is very helpful thank you very much. I think I started to get the concept of null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
        String stringValue = "";
        
        if (grade <= 45 && grade >= 35) {
            stringValue = "FD";
        } else if (grade <= 52 && grade >= 46) {
            stringValue = "DD";
        } else if (grade <= 59 && grade >= 53) {
            stringValue = "DC";
        } else if (grade <= 66 && grade >= 60) {
            stringValue = "CC";
        } else if (grade <= 73 && grade >= 67) {
            stringValue = "CB";
        } else if (grade <= 80 && grade >= 74) {
            stringValue = "BB";
        } else if (grade <= 87 && grade >= 81) {
            stringValue = "BA";
        } else if (grade <= 100 && grade >= 88) {
            stringValue = "AA";
        } else {
            stringValue =  "FF";
        }

        return stringValue;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(gradeLetter(75.59));
    }
}
```

Comment: *Try this* is not an anser. Explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: I only removed the redundant variable `c` from the function, because a single variable is enough to do the job, renamed `a`, and added `if-else` statements for the comparison. Also, if the value of `grade` goes beyond 100 then the function will return `FF`, which is in a way "an undefined result" for an input that goes beyond 100.

Comment: This explanation should be par of your answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems here:
1)Variable a is not declared in case grade>100 and programm will throw an error in this cases
2)There is no need to check all this conditions because only one will be true so you should better use if else if statements like:

```
public static String gradeLetter(double grade) {
        String a ="";
        if (grade<=34) {
            a = "FF";
        }else if (grade<=45 && grade >= 35) {
            a = "FD";
        }else if (grade<=52 && grade >= 46) {
            a = "DD";
        }else if (grade<=59 && grade >= 53) {
            a = "DC";
        }else if (grade<=66 && grade >= 60) {
            a = "CC";
        }else if (grade<=73 && grade >= 67) {
            a = "CB";
        }else if (grade<=80 && grade >= 74) {
             a = "BB";
        }else if (grade<=87 && grade >= 81) {
            a = "BA";
        }else if (grade<=100 && grade >= 88) {
            a = "AA";
        }
        return a;
 }
```

This way you will make sure that your method will return a value (even if this is an empty string) and you wont spend time checking if statements that will be false

Comment: The concatinate with the empty string `c` makes no sence.